# How to know online or offline of user in smack in one to one chat?

Tags: android, smack

I have tried this code and all the snippet available still cannot able to receive the online or offline presence of the user. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
fun checkStatus() {
    val jid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom("QTX69RGLVQ3VVU8QUB@localhost")

    var roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection)
    var availability = roster.getPresence(jid);
    var  userMode = availability.getMode();
    retrieveState_mode(userMode, availability.isAvailable)
}

fun retrieveState_mode(userMode: Presence.Mode, isOnline:Boolean):Int {
    var userState = 0;
    if(userMode == Presence.Mode.dnd) {
        userState = 3;
    } else if (userMode == Presence.Mode.away || userMode == Presence.Mode.xa) {
        userState = 2;
    } else if (isOnline) {
        userState = 1;
    }
    return userState
}
```

Always I'm getting as 0

Comment: `getPresence` is asynchronous, so you have to hook up event listener, and only when the server responds with the result, you'll know

Comment: @Pierre can u suggest link  so that i can look into it please

Comment: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/documentation/roster.md
Sorry - this should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first. If you read this:

https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0162.html

you will find this:
subscription='both': You and the contact are interested in each other's presence information.

So if your roster is set to subscription='both', you both must be in each other roster (lets say buddy request and approval in both directions)
to listen to each others presence information.

So knowing previous, the way I have done it using Smack is:

```
//Created presence packet listener
private StanzaListener presencePacketListener;

//In my connection creating
private XMPPTCPConnection createConnection() throws XmppStringprepException {
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config =  XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        .......
        config.setSendPresence(true);
        .......
        return new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
}

//Then in login method
public void login() throws SmackInvocationException, XmppStringprepException {
        connect();
        try {
            //Add presencePacketListener to listen for subscribed users (Roster) presence
            con.addSyncStanzaListener(presencePacketListener, new StanzaTypeFilter(Presence.class));
            //Actual login
            .....
            onConnectionEstablished();
        } catch(Exception e) {          
            throw exception;
        }
}

// onConnectionEstablished method
private void onConnectionEstablished() {
        if (state != State.CONNECTED) {         
            sendPacket(new Presence(Presence.Type.available));
        }
}
```

When doing

> sendPacket(new Presence(Presence.Type.available));

all users in your roster subscription will receive this presence packet.
That will be processed in

> presencePacketListener

that we have registered earlier on login.

```
//PresencePacketListener
public class PresencePacketListener implements StanzaListener {
    private Context context;

    PresencePacketListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void processStanza(Stanza packet) {
        Presence presence = (Presence)packet;
        Presence.Type presenceType = presence.getType();
        //Do sth with presence
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it worked . i was missing subscription  thank you .

Answer (score 0):

### Listening for Roster and Presence Changes

> The typical use of the roster class is to display a tree view of groups and entries along with the current presence value of each entry. As an example, see the image showing a Roster in the Exodus XMPP client to the right.
>
> The presence information will likely change often, and it's also possible for the roster entries to change or be deleted. To listen for changing roster and presence data, a RosterListener should be used. To be informed about all changes to the roster the RosterListener should be registered before logging into the XMPP server. The following code snippet registers a RosterListener with the Roster that prints any presence changes in the roster to standard out. A normal client would use similar code to update the roster UI with the changing information.

```
Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(con);
roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
    // Ignored events public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) {}
    public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {}
    public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {}
    public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
        System.out.println("Presence changed: " + presence.getFrom() + " " + presence);
    }
});
```

Note that in order to receive presence changed events you need to be subscribed to the users presence. See the following section.

[Source](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/documentation/roster.md)